# Vue 3 transition flickers on start

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, transition, vuejs3

I've built myself a carousel of divs that slide in and out of the screen. My problem is that on the start of every transition, when the new div first renders (ie. the carousel_2 key changes), it seems to render without the transition-enter class applied to it. This means that the new div flickers overtop of the old one before getting translated off the screen and out of view. It's almost as though the transition takes a tick to register that the new div has appeared. If I could figure out how to delay the new div from rendering for a tick, I believe that my problem might be solved, though I don't know how to do this with keys.

```
<transition name="slide-img">
    <div :key="carousel_2" class="workDiv-container">
        <div class="workDiv">
            <div class="imgDiv">
                <img :src="carousel_2.img" style="width: 100%;"/>
            </div>

            <div class="infoDiv">
                <h1>{{ carousel_2.title }}</h1>
                <h3>{{ carousel_2.creator }}</h3>
                <h3>{{ carousel_2.date }}</h3>
                <h3>{{ carousel_2.medium }}</h3>
                <h3>{{ carousel_2.idno }}</h3>
                <h3>{{ carousel_2.dimensions }}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                                                                   
</transition>

.slide-img-enter {
    left: -100%;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.slide-img-enter-to {
    left: -100%;
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
.slide-img-enter-active {
    transition: transform 2s;
}

.slide-img-leave {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.slide-img-leave-to {
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
.slide-img-leave-active {
    transition: transform 2s;
}

.workDiv-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

NOTE: carousel_2 is just a computed value that is updated with the object containing the values to display.

Comment: [Docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State) - *Don’t use non-primitive values like objects and arrays as `v-for` keys. Use string or numeric values instead.*

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to have fixed anything. If it helps at all, this is the link to the site: https://bachinski-chu.uoguelph.ca/Exhibition.html?ref=10 if you scroll to the bottom you'll see the carousel. The flicker seems to get worse once the cards return to the beginning and start to repeat for the second scan.

Comment: I didn't say it will help. It interesting to see it running but [Minimal, reproducible  and runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (jsfiddle/codepen etc) would be better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> on the start of every transition, when the new div first renders (ie. the carousel_2 key changes), it seems to render without the transition-enter class applied to it

That's right. Because In Vue 3 the `v-enter` and `v-leave` classes are [renamed](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/transition.html#frontmatter-title) to `v-enter-from` and `v-leave-from`

If you change your transition classes to:

```css
.slide-img-enter-from {
  left: -100%;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
/* this one is actually not needed at all */
.slide-img-leave-from {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

...the problem is fixed. [Demo](https://codepen.io/liwoj/pen/mdwyjKv)